# When I run "python .\manage.py runserver" I get this: No Python at '"C:\Users\Utilizador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

virtual environment activated

```
(env) PS C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\FSapp> python .\manage.py runserver 
No Python at 

'"C:\Users\Utilizador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe'
```

---

virtual environment deactivated

```
PS C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\FSapp> python .\manage.py runserver 
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that    
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python .\manage.py runserver
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException     
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

---

When using "python3 .\manage.py runserver" I get

```
python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify   
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python3 .\manage.py runserver
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException    
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

---

IMPORTANT:

- I'm using django and nodejs to build a full stack application
- I installed all the packages while having the virtual envirnmont "env" activated.

Here are my system variables:

[image: Here are my system variables]

Here are my users variables:

[image: Here are my users variables]